# Plotting $\sqrt{z}$ where z is a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I try to plot the image of the domain $-\infty<x<\infty$ and $0<y<\pi$ under the function $w=\sqrt{z}$. I've got a hint that one boundary is a hyperbola.

I tried sth like that:

$w^2=z=x+iy \ \ \ \ \  w=u+iv \\ (u+iv)^2=u^2+2iuv-v^2 \\ u^2-v^2=x \ \ \ \ y=2vu \Rightarrow u={y \over 2v} \\ {y^2 \over 4v^2}-v^2=x \\ {y^2 \over4}-v^4=xv^2 \\ v^2={-x\pm \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \over 2 } \\ v=\pm {\sqrt{-x\pm \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \over 2}} \\ u=\pm {y \over 2\sqrt{-x\pm \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \over 2} }$

I'm not sure if it is a right approach to such kind of problem.

Comment: $-\infty<x<\infty$ and $0<x<\pi$? One of those variables should be $y$, I assume?

Comment: You're right. My mistake. It's corrected, now.

Answer (score 1):

You went too far.  Once you have $2uv=y$ then you know you have a hyperbola for any specific nonzero $y$ and of course the $u, v$ axes (to which the hyperbola are asymptotic) for $y=0$.  So put in $y=0$ and $y=\pi$ with that information and get your boundaries.